# Matplotlib is not working as it used to on pycharm. How can I solve it?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

**Note: I am just a beginner and doing this by myself, so if you can reply with basic descriptions, that could help more.**

**This is the code I wrote**

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot([2, 1], [8, 2], 'ro')
```

**However, I get this error. I had a code using same way to import and it used to work just fine. Now that code is not working either.**

```
C:\Users\Tuna\PycharmProjects\start\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Tuna/PycharmProjects/start/matplotlib.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tuna\PycharmProjects\start\matplotlib.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\Tuna\PycharmProjects\start\matplotlib.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
ImportError: cannot import name 'pyplot' from partially initialized module 'matplotlib' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Tuna\PycharmProjects\start\matplotlib.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Do you have a  python file named `matplotlib.py` apart of installing `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 0):

To fix, you just need to rename your file to something that isn't matplotlib.py. Python thinks you are trying to import your own file matplotlib.py to use rather than the actual module and hence why you are getting a circular reference.
This should work fine if you have matplotlib installed, if not pycharm should prompt you to install it which should be the easiest way for you to use it in your project.